# How to correctly configure Selenium WebDriver, in a way it doesn't affect browsing?

Tags: c#, selenium, proxy, webdriver

I'm currently developing a workflow test for a webapp with selenium, however it seems to be breaking the ability of all browsers to browse beyond a local web page for all browsers. Before using the app that uses selenium everything works fine for all browsers, when I run it it is when it affects all browsers.

I running the app with IE as is a must, doing it on IE11 on windows 7, with zoom on 100% and protected mode enabled for all sites.

Code sample below

```
var o = new InternetExplorerOptions();
var p = new Proxy();
p.IsAutoDetect = true;
o.Proxy = proxy;
o.PageLoadStrategy = InternetExplorerPageLoadStrategy.Normal;
o.EnableNativeEvents = false;
o.IgnoreZoomLevel = true;
o.RequireWindowFocus = false;
o.IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true;

var d = new InternetExplorerDriver(options);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("local site goes here");
```

Answer (score 0):

Including and modifying the code sample shared by you. Hope this helps :

```
// proxy configs
Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
proxy.IsAutoDetect = true;
// IE options config
InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
options.Proxy = proxy;
options.PageLoadStrategy = InternetExplorerPageLoadStrategy.Normal;
options.EnableNativeEvents = false;
options.IgnoreZoomLevel = true;
options.RequireWindowFocus = false;
options.IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true;
// driver capabilities config
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
//driver initialisation
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("local site goes here");
```